# Calling java api from objective c

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I am developing android and ios app. My question is that, in my android app i use Apachi POI api for reading .doc and .docx files but in my ios app i cannot use Apachi POI. Is there any way to use Java api in objective c? If there is no way, Can i manually  convert Apachi POI to objective c?

Comment: Just a note - you can use `UIWebView` in Objective-C to display documents and such.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run Java on iOS. Java needs a virtual machine to run.

You can manually convert any Java code you want, if you know Obj-C well enough. You can also look for java -> obj-c converters which can help you in the conversion a little.

Note that this would be a very long work, not something you can do in a month.

The easist solution is to find a C/C++/Obj-C library or implement only the specific parts of `docx` you need.

Comment: In the future, you will be able to use JavaFX cross platform on both Android and iOS - however there are a lot of speculations on how the performance-penalty will be on iOS, because of the VM that are needed, afaik.